# Is the US position to block Deep UV immersion lithography equipment and technology from reaching China a "blockade" or "unfair practice"?

Tags: united-states, china, technology, netherlands

Different but related:

- [How the US (and five others) define "economic coercion" they condemn, and differentiate it from the economic tools they use to pressure countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79906/16047)

---

The South China Morning Post's November 23, 2022 article [The Netherlands resists US call to ban more chip-making equipment sales to China, pledges to defend interests](https://www.scmp.com/tech/big-tech/article/3200643/netherlands-resists-us-call-ban-more-chip-making-equipment-sales-china-pledges-defend-interests) (which looks like it's originally from  a [paywalled Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-22/dutch-resist-us-call-to-ban-more-chip-equipment-sales-to-china) includes the following:

> While ASML hasn’t sold any of its most advanced extreme ultraviolet lithography machines to China because the Dutch government has refused to grant it a license under US pressure, the company can still sell less sophisticated chipmaking systems to the Asian country.
>
> However, US officials have been pressuring the Dutch government to ban the sales of immersion lithography machines, the most advanced kind of gear in ASML’s deep ultraviolet line-up, Bloomberg News has reported. The Biden administration has been working to get allies including the Netherlands and Japan to adopt the sweeping measures it unveiled in early October to ban more chip machines for China.

*If I understand correctly,* semiconductor fabs in China are already using deep ultraviolet (DUV) [immersion lithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_lithography) tools from ASML in manufacturing, and the US now wants not only to block [extreme ultraviolet lithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_ultraviolet_lithography) (EUV) but also any further DUV-immersion equipment and technology from reaching China, something which is already in use there.

1. Have I got that right?
2. Can the extension these technology blockings for China into *DUV immersion photolithography* be seen as a "technology blockade" or "unfair practice" in the context of accepted norms and practices in international trade?

Comment: related: [What political apparatus and rules allow the United States to have leverage against companies when it has several intellectual properties associated?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/74256/16047) and [How exactly can keeping chips using EUV technology "pre-empt many worst-case human rights... scenarios in the coming decades?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70738/16047) and [Which "critical technologies" does Russia dependent upon the United States and its allies for, that "China does not have access to?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70632/16047)

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess that at least one answer will be of the form "Yes it could be seen that way but that doesn't stop the US from doing it all the time."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what difference it makes that China already uses some of this? Either the whole thing is a blockade or none of it? The intended result: China not getting more ASML machines is the same.

Comment: @Trilarion then you don't have much experience in manufacturing. If you have a billion dollar fab running product that depends on a particular capital equipment investment and suddenly you can't get service, parts, consumables or software upgrades, not only does your investment suddenly depreciate to near zero, but your cash flow suffers and your customers go elsewhere - permanently. It's a *huge difference!*

Comment: Is it really a difference in the end compared to not being able to invest in the future, not selling products and not making profits? Sure, missing future profits are a different accounting category than writing -off past investments but the net effect is the same: you lose money and nobody knows in which case you lose more. If ASML (pressured by US or anyone else) says that they don't sell anymore to China, what possible legal arguments can China bring? A right to spare parts maybe? Environmentally that might be reasonable.

Comment: @Trilarion yes, of course they are different. In issues of commerce there are just for example fair and unfair practices; both can result in a company or economy losing money, but that alone doesn't make them the same thing.

Comment: You mean particular terms in commerce, because general fair or unfair are moral categories and I'm not sure cutting off somebody from future developments is any fairer than cutting them off from recent developments.

Comment: It could be an unfair practice, but not a [blockade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockade?wprov=sfla1), unless the United States is besieging Beijing and I missed it.

Comment: It's a trade restriction measure.  Not a blockade.  **Is it fair?  We won't know until the WTO rules on that.**  China also engages in similar behavior on occasion, even at the export end.  Have you forgotten? https://www.ft.com/content/d3ed83f4-19bc-4d16-b510-415749c032c1 https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/dispu_e/cases_e/ds431_e.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare_earths_trade_dispute  Now, we already have 2 Qs about this subject, how is this 3rd one required *and* different?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica how does one decide on their own that there can only be two and not three questions about a given subject? Some subjects have dozens of questions.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.  The US government wouldn't be able to block it for the reason of wanting to impose a preferential trade practice.  And it's not a blockade because there are no military personal actively involved in blocking the process.

Since the given justification is that it would have military use, it's withholding of a military secret.  That is something the government is very much authorized to do.

Comment: I disagree. It would be withholding a military secret, if the technology were american. It's a dutch company, though, and the Netherlands doesn't seem to think it's a military secret. The USA opinion should be irrelevant then.

Comment: The USA may argue that the bits and pieces of American-licensed tech in it are a military secret, but once the USA willingly gave them to a Dutch company to bake in a civilian product, it does seem a weak defence.

Answer (score -1):

How about "an attempt to sit on two chairs at once"?

During the last decades, the USA have been positioning themself as an uncontested leader of the world united by free global trade whose superiority stems from having best technologies, science and business practices.

However, blockading China from getting the tech that it wants displays the American insecurity in maintaining its superiority. So in essense they start to copy the Chinese practices of firewalling its economic system instead. Which is naturally better suited to siloed economies world than free trade world.

It is definitely a blockade but it is not an unfair practice for the owner of most advanced economic silo in the world that wants to preserve their advantage. For the leader of free trade world, definitely an unfair practice.